# How to speed up one hot encoder code

Tags: python, performance, numpy

I made simple function that will return an output one hot encoded matrix when given as input one vector.

```
import numpy as np

def ohc(x):
    u = list(set(x))
    c = len(u)
    X = np.zeros((len(x), c))
    for idx, val in enumerate(x):
        for i in range(c):
            if val == u[i]:
                X[idx, i] = 1
    return X

inputx = np.random.randint(1, 4, 1000000)
ohc(inputx) 
Out[2]: 
array([[ 0.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  0.],
       ..., 
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  0.]])
```

but I'm wondering if because of those two for loops there is any way to speed it up?

```
     1000006 function calls in 1.102 seconds

   Ordered by: standard name

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
    1    0.930    0.930    1.102    1.102 <ipython-input-32-fcf6d323f906>:1(ohc)
    1    0.000    0.000    1.102    1.102 <string>:1(<module>)
    2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {len}
    1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
    1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {numpy.core.multiarray.zeros}
  1000000    0.172    0.000    0.172    0.000 {range}
```

Comment: Have you profiled the code to see where the bottleneck is? It strikes me that by using the vanilla `list` and `set` classes, you may be negating some of the benefit numpy can have. Perhaps there are numpy equivalents to do what you want and make the operations a bit faster.

Comment: @PaulRooney wasn't aware of the profiler, if I'm reading it right its the range that takes the longest ? I've added the output in the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like a job for `np.unique`

```
uniq, inv = np.unique(x, return_inverse=True)
result = np.zeros((len(x), len(uniq)), dtype=int)
result[np.arange(len(x)), inv] = 1
```

In response to @Divakar's benchmarks: Here is a more informative comparison confirming a slight speed advantage for `dv` at small alphabets, which crosses over around `K=20` and reverses into a severalfold advantage for `pp` at `K=1000`. This is expected since `pp` takes advantage of the sparsity of one-hot. Below, *K* is the size of the alphabet, *N* the length of the sample.

```
import numpy as np
from timeit import timeit

def pp(x):
    uniq, inv = np.unique(x, return_inverse=True)
    result = np.zeros((len(x), len(uniq)), dtype=int)
    result[np.arange(len(x)), inv] = 1

def dv(x):
    (x[:,None] == np.unique(x)).astype(int)


for K in (4, 10, 20, 40, 100, 200, 1000):
    tpp, tdv = [], []
    print('@ K =', K)
    for N in (1000, 10000, 100000):
        data = np.random.choice(np.random.random(K), N, replace=True)
        tdv.append(timeit('f(a)', number=100, globals={'f': dv, 'a': data}))
        tpp.append(timeit('f(a)', number=100, globals={'f': pp, 'a': data}))
    print('dv:', '{:.6f}, {:.6f}, {:.6f}'.format(*tdv), 'secs for 100 trials @ N = 1000, 10000, 100000')
    print('pp:', '{:.6f}, {:.6f}, {:.6f}'.format(*tpp), 'secs for 100 trials @ N = 1000, 10000, 100000')
```

Prints:

```
@ K = 4
dv: 0.003458, 0.038176, 0.421894 secs for 100 trials @ N = 1000, 10000, 100000
pp: 0.004856, 0.052298, 0.603758 secs for 100 trials @ N = 1000, 10000, 100000
@ K = 10
dv: 0.005136, 0.056491, 0.663157 secs for 100 trials @ N = 1000, 10000, 100000
pp: 0.005955, 0.054069, 0.719152 secs for 100 trials @ N = 1000, 10000, 100000
@ K = 20
dv: 0.007201, 0.084867, 0.988886 secs for 100 trials @ N = 1000, 10000, 100000
pp: 0.007638, 0.084580, 0.891122 secs for 100 trials @ N = 1000, 10000, 100000
@ K = 40
dv: 0.010748, 0.130974, 1.498022 secs for 100 trials @ N = 1000, 10000, 100000
pp: 0.009321, 0.103912, 1.080271 secs for 100 trials @ N = 1000, 10000, 100000
@ K = 100
dv: 0.025357, 0.292930, 2.946326 secs for 100 trials @ N = 1000, 10000, 100000
pp: 0.011916, 0.147117, 1.641588 secs for 100 trials @ N = 1000, 10000, 100000
@ K = 200
dv: 0.033651, 0.560753, 6.042001 secs for 100 trials @ N = 1000, 10000, 100000
pp: 0.022971, 0.221142, 3.580255 secs for 100 trials @ N = 1000, 10000, 100000
@ K = 1000
dv: 0.156715, 2.655647, 37.112166 secs for 100 trials @ N = 1000, 10000, 100000
pp: 0.055516, 0.920938, 10.358050 secs for 100 trials @ N = 1000, 10000, 100000
```

Using `uint8` and allowing @Divakar's method to use the cheaper view-casting:

```
@ K = 4
dv: 0.003092, 0.038149, 0.386140 secs for 100 trials @ N = 1000, 10000, 100000
pp: 0.004392, 0.043327, 0.554253 secs for 100 trials @ N = 1000, 10000, 100000
@ K = 10
dv: 0.004604, 0.054215, 0.501708 secs for 100 trials @ N = 1000, 10000, 100000
pp: 0.004930, 0.051555, 0.607239 secs for 100 trials @ N = 1000, 10000, 100000
@ K = 20
dv: 0.006421, 0.067397, 0.665465 secs for 100 trials @ N = 1000, 10000, 100000
pp: 0.006616, 0.054055, 0.703260 secs for 100 trials @ N = 1000, 10000, 100000
@ K = 40
dv: 0.008857, 0.087155, 0.862316 secs for 100 trials @ N = 1000, 10000, 100000
pp: 0.006945, 0.060408, 0.733966 secs for 100 trials @ N = 1000, 10000, 100000
@ K = 100
dv: 0.015660, 0.142464, 1.426929 secs for 100 trials @ N = 1000, 10000, 100000
pp: 0.008063, 0.070860, 0.908615 secs for 100 trials @ N = 1000, 10000, 100000
@ K = 200
dv: 0.025631, 0.235712, 2.401750 secs for 100 trials @ N = 1000, 10000, 100000
pp: 0.008805, 0.101772, 1.111652 secs for 100 trials @ N = 1000, 10000, 100000
@ K = 1000
dv: 0.069953, 1.024585, 11.313402 secs for 100 trials @ N = 1000, 10000, 100000
pp: 0.011558, 0.182684, 2.201837 secs for 100 trials @ N = 1000, 10000, 100000
```

Comment: Good to see the relevant trade-offs there. Nice job on benchmarking too!

Comment: @Divakar Thanks! Feel free to use the view-casting optimisation in your post.

Comment: sorry i keep changing which answer i accepted but i wanted to make sure i tested each for the cases that I would likely use. it's a really hard choice considering how simple @Divakar answer is, but my main concern was speed so I think it's only fair to accept PP answer

Answer (score 4):

Here's a vectorized approach using only the unique values from [`np.unique`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) for comparison against the original array for getting to the one-hot encoded array -

```
(inputx[:,None] == np.unique(inputx)).astype(float)
```

**Runtime test**

Other approaches -

```
# Original soln
def ohc(x):
    u = list(set(x))
    c = len(u)
    X = np.zeros((len(x), c))
    for idx, val in enumerate(x):
        for i in range(c):
            if val == u[i]:
                X[idx, i] = 1
    return X

# @Tommalla's soln
def ohc_dict(x):
    elem_to_idx = {}
    for e in x:
        if e not in elem_to_idx:
            elem_to_idx[e] = len(elem_to_idx)
    c = len(elem_to_idx)
    X = np.zeros((len(x), c))
    for idx, val in enumerate(x):
        X[idx, elem_to_idx[val]] = 1
    return X

# @Paul Panzer's soln   
def unique_inverse(x):
    uniq, inv = np.unique(x, return_inverse=True)
    result = np.zeros((len(x), len(uniq)), dtype=int)
    result[np.arange(len(x)), inv] = 1
    return result
```

Timings -

```
In [42]: inputx = np.random.randint(1, 4, 1000000)

In [43]: %timeit ohc(inputx)
1 loops, best of 3: 526 ms per loop

In [44]: %timeit ohc_dict(inputx)
1 loops, best of 3: 256 ms per loop

In [45]: %timeit unique_inverse(inputx)
10 loops, best of 3: 48.6 ms per loop

In [46]: %timeit (inputx[:,None] == np.unique(inputx)).astype(float)
10 loops, best of 3: 34.4 ms per loop
```

**Further performance boost-**

Use `np.int8` as the output dtype for further performance boost with the proposed method -

```
In [58]: %timeit (inputx[:,None] == np.unique(inputx)).astype(np.int8)
10 loops, best of 3: 27.7 ms per loop
```

As suggested by @Paul Panzer, we can also use `view` instead of type-casting for some further boost on arrays with more unique numbers -

```
In [23]: inputx = np.random.randint(1, 40, 1000000)

In [24]: %timeit (inputx[:,None] == np.unique(inputx)).astype(np.int8)
10 loops, best of 3: 98.4 ms per loop

In [25]: %timeit (inputx[:,None] == np.unique(inputx)).view(np.int8)
10 loops, best of 3: 92.5 ms per loop
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code runs in O(n *[because of set()]* + nc *[because of the for loops]*). In most practical applications you will end up with O(nc) anyway*, because you need to allocate the space for the array. There's a couple tricks to make it more efficient however:

1. Use a dict. Dicts are implemented using hashing, which should on average take constant time.
2. Don't iterate over c possible features at every step, but memorize the index for every feature.

Here's my implementation:

```
import numpy as np

def ohc(x):
    elem_to_idx = {}
    for e in x:
        if e not in elem_to_idx:
            elem_to_idx[e] = len(elem_to_idx)
    c = len(elem_to_idx)
    X = np.zeros((len(x), c))
    for idx, val in enumerate(x):
        X[idx, elem_to_idx[val]] = 1
    return X
```

** depending on what you intend to do with the X matrix, you might want to use numpy.sparse matrix, which does not allocate that much memory and in turn can make your code run in O(n) instead of O(nc)*